# Using in_array for array

Tags: php, arrays

So, I have the following php:

```
<?php 
$user_id = get_current_user_id();   
$user_number= get_user_meta($user_id, 'number', false); 
$numbers= print_r($user_number);    
?>
```

I get the following:

```
Array
(
[0] =&gt; Array
    (
        [1] =&gt; 769099
        [2] =&gt; 768785
        [3] =&gt; 769135
        [4] =&gt; 769118
        [5] =&gt; 769136
        [6] =&gt; 769122
        [7] =&gt; 769130
    )

)
```

Now, I am trying to use `in_array` to add a condition as following:

```
<?php if (in_array ($number_id, $numbers)){?>
```

where $number_id is one of the number in the array.

I have two questions:

Do I have to use `print_r` to get the values instead of simply saying `Array` in order to use `in_array`?

How do I actually user `in_array`? in this case?

(For example, using the `get_user_meta`, I simply get `Array`. I don't want to use `print_r`. How do I do this? Thanks!)

Comment: in_array(value, $array)

Comment: ` $numbers` is multidimension.  use `in_array ($number_id, $numbers[0])`

Comment: what's the difference between `0` and `1`?

Comment: the `[0]` means the index of the `array` you want to check

Answer (score 3):

`print_r()` is normally print your array. Your code Should be:

```
<?php 
$user_id = get_current_user_id();   
$user_number= get_user_meta($user_id, 'number', false);   
?>
```

If you want to check `number_id` in your `current user number` array than your code should be :

```
if(in_array('769118',$user_number[0])){ // 769118 is $number_id
    echo "Match Found";
}else{
    echo "No Match Found";  
}
```

You can refer this link : [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 1):

`print_r()` is only a function to display the values within an array.

In your case the function `get_user_meta()`  retrieve the numbers associated with the user_id and nothing more.

And the function `in_array()` is there to check to the existence of a specific value within an array.

Comment: So, I got rid of `print_r`. And `<?php if (in_array ($number_id, $user_number)){?>` Is this correct? (doesn't seem to work)...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php if (in_array ($number_id, $user_number[0])){?>
```

Comment: what's the difference between `0` and `1`?

Comment: There is a difference.. `0 != 1`.. this answer doesn't solve the problem.. @Sugumar you've added 2 answer but both are wrong.. you should pay more attention before adding answers